# getelement in excel VBA

Tags: html, vba, excel

I am new, to the field of programing.

I like to know, how to write code for getelement in excel vba, for extracting expiry date (30/Nov/2017) from the below html code.

Tried a lot in writing code, but could not succeed also F8 is not working in my excel VBA.

So, I am seeking help of you peoples.

```
</TABLE>
</TD>
<TD></TD></TR>
<TR><TD></TD>
<TD COLSPAN=3 CLASS='subheader2' ALIGN='LEFT'><SPAN ID='spanLicense'CLASS='showHide' onMouseOver="this.style.cursor='pointer';" onMouseOut="this.style.cursor='auto';" onClick ="ShowHideDetails('license');">-</SPAN>&nbsp;License Details</TD>
<TD></TD></TR>
<TR><TD></TD>
<TD COLSPAN=3 ALIGN='right'>
<div id='divLicense' name='divLicense' style = 'display:none'><table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0  align='center'></table></div>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href='#spanBasic'>Top</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a HREF='#spanBottom'>Bottom</a></TD>
<TD></TD></TR>
<TR><TD></TD>
<TD COLSPAN=3 CLASS = 'hline'>&nbsp;</TD>
<TD></TD></TR>
<TR ID='trLicenseInfoContainer'><TD></TD>
<TD COLSPAN=3>
<TABLE width='100%' CELLSPACING='0' BORDER='0' CELLPADDING='2' ALIGN='CENTER'>
<TR>
<TD WIDTH='24%'></TD>
<TD WIDTH='1%'></TD>
<TD WIDTH='75%'></TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD ALIGN='LEFT' CLASS=odd>Issue date</TD>
<TD ALIGN='LEFT' CLASS=odd>:</TD>
<TD ALIGN='LEFT' CLASS=odd>27-May-2017 02:34:00 PM</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD ALIGN='LEFT' CLASS=even>Expiry date</TD>
<TD ALIGN='LEFT' CLASS=even>:</TD>
<TD ALIGN='LEFT' CLASS=even></TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD ALIGN='LEFT' CLASS=odd>Tally Software Services  subscription</TD>
<TD ALIGN='LEFT' CLASS=odd>:</TD>
<TD ALIGN='LEFT' CLASS=odd>Active (Expires on ***30-Nov-2017***)&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href = 'javascript:;' onclick = 'renewTSS(200203221,200203221,29514);' style='color:green' >Renew TSS</a></TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD ALIGN='LEFT' CLASS=even>XBRL  subscription</TD>
<TD ALIGN='LEFT' CLASS=even>:</TD>
<TD ALIGN='LEFT' CLASS=even>Expired on 31-Mar-2016</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD ALIGN='LEFT' CLASS=odd>Offline Limit</TD>
<TD ALIGN='LEFT' CLASS=odd>:</TD>
<TD ALIGN='LEFT' CLASS=odd>30</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD ALIGN='LEFT' CLASS=even>TVP</TD>
<TD ALIGN='LEFT' CLASS=even>:</TD>
<TD ALIGN='LEFT' CLASS=even>Expired on 31-Oct-2007</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
```

Comment: Do you have this data in an excel sheet? pls post the image of that excel.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim TheDate As String
Dim StartLoc As String 

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")


With ie
    .Visible = True
    .navigate "https://URL_to_naviagte_to"

' Wait for the page to fully load; you can't do anything if the page is not fully loaded
Do While .Busy Or _
    .ReadyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Loop


' Possible Solution # 1
' Find the date string in the page
TheDate = "***"
StartLoc = InStr(1, ie.document.body.innerhtml, TheDate)
        GoOver = Mid(span.innerhtml, StartLoc + 3, 11)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, i guess d question tat i asked didnot meet the requirement let me reframe it, i have a set of product license numbers for which i have to extract expiry date from the web page.
if i use getelementbytagname("td"), there are more than 1 element with with tagname "td".
if i use getelementbyclassname("odd"), there are more than 1 element with classname "odd".
hence i thought of getting the element using xpath //*[@id="trLicenseInfoContainer"]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[4]/tr[3] this is d xpath to the element. since vba excel doesnot have any builtin method to get xpath element how do i do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CSS selector of

```
Debug.print ie.document.querySelectorAll("td.odd").Item(5).innerText
```

This looks for elements with td tag having class name odd and selects the matched element at index 5 (0 based index). This is based on the html you supplied.

[image: Add data]